# How does npm build know what url to proxy - where is this instruction stored?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

If in development the url to fetch is set by placing HOST=whattofetch within the .env file and using the proxy line in package.json;

how is this set up in production?

I have tried changing the .env file but it doesn't make a difference in the url that it fetches, so my question is "where does it pull the information from?"

Comment: Afaik, the `proxy` field applies to development mode only anyway; it is assumed that a built react app is hosted on the same domain as the api it's accessing, so in production the URLs will "just work".

Comment: `process.env.NODE_ENV` should give which environment the application is running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create two `.env` files, `.env` and `.env.prod` at the root level. You can define your particular 'variables' related to specific environment into these `env` files. Then in your code you should be able to access them through `process.env.NODE_ENV`

```
if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
    //Execute this in production environment
    var url= `${process.env.REACT_APP_AC_ORIGIN}/`;
    url = url + ...,
}else{
    //Execute this in dev environment
    var url= `${process.env.REACT_APP_AC_ORIGIN}/`;
    url = url + ...,
}
```

**.env**

`REACT_APP_AC_ORIGIN=https://example1.com`

**.env.prod**

`REACT_APP_AC_ORIGIN=https://example2.com`